# Comments on answered questions.

Tags: bug

I was attempting to comment on an answered post here on Stack Exchange with my phone. Unfortunately, as a novice user I'm unable to just yet. It wasn't very apparent to me at first though!

Here's what I noticed: 
There was no feedback when tapping the add comment link.

The error I recieved was displayed on a tooltip. Something about the site's responsive styles caused it to show up off-screen . In order to see it I had to zoom out.

Comment: Are you using the Stack Exchange app, or us a browser to access the standard web url? In either case, http://meta.stackexchange.com/ is likely the better place to be addressing this.